# How to design classes and db table in right way for recurring Order?

Tags: c#, design, database, object-oriented-design

I have requirement like user can booked space (office, room, meeting room etc) for a rent for particular time period. But requirement is like user required to booked space every month 5th date, or they need that meeting room in every week Friday.

I have no idea from where to start for store data.
How to design class or table for requirement.

I have tried for table design like.

```
public partial class OrderListing 
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double ListingPrice { get; set; }
        public bool IsRepeatEveryWeek { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? RecurringEndDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsCountPricePerDay { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
}

public class OrderHourlyListingRecurring : Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Entity
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
        public int OrderHourlyListingID { get; set; }
        public virtual OrderListing OrderHourlyListing { get; set; }
}
```

Is this correct or required some changes?

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Answer (score 0):

As a general tip, look at how Outlook handles this.

Example, a recurring apointment every 19th of the month:
[image]

You can build your classes containing the fields you need for your case.